# Why nominative instead of accusative with verb "sum"?

Tags: accusative, nominativus

Recently I've been learning about the accusative case, in/direct objects and in/transitive verbs. In light of this, consider the phrase:

> *Nilus fluvius est*

I'm interested in the rationale (*rationalis*?) of why the above uses *fluvius* instead of *fluvium*. In particular:

1. is *fluvius* a direct object? Since "what is" is *fluvius*, I would thought so.
2. is the verb *sum* (beside being a copulative verb) a transitive verb? I would have thought so too, since it is a verb that *can* take an object (I am a human; human being the object taken by the verb to be).

But then why *fluvius* and not *fluvium*? If 1 is not true, then what is the function/structure of the object (noun/adjective) next to the copulative verb "to be"?

[I can see](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sum#Latin) that when using the verb "sum" (except in its "to have" meaning), the case for the "object" of the verb is in nominative. 
But I see no reference to this exception when reading about the accusative case (which is supposed to be the case of the direct object next to a transitive verb).

Comment: Because sum is not a transitive verb and fluvius is not an object. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicative_expression

Comment: @AlexB. I think this is a circular argument. “Sum” is not a transitive verb precisely because it does not take an accusative object.

Comment: @fbd I don't see any circular argument there. A canonical definition of a transitive verb is the one that takes a direct object (aka THEME; no, I'm not screaming - it's a convention to capitalize thematic roles, at least in some theories). The direct object is usually understood as an argument directly affected/changed by the predicate (if I'm remembering William Frawley *Linguistic Semantics* correctly). . If you want to define transitivity differently, no problem with me. Btw I didn't say that the direct object has to be in the accusative. :)

Comment: @AlexB.: So are you suggesting that direct objects ought to be limited to certain thematic roles (probably not)? Or are you arguing from a prototype, where the theme is the most typical role on which we should base the frameworks of our definition of a direct object? I admit it is a difficult problem to define the most basic terms in linguistics, when you have almost no other blocks available yet to build with...

Comment: @Cerberus I use theme here in the sense of a semantic role that "undergoes the action/change/event expressed by the verb" (I copied this definition from Sebastian Löbner *Understanding semantics* - Löbner 2013); this would be equivalent to the Undergoer (macrorole). Of course, that would include patient, theme (in the narrow sense), source etc. And yes, the subject is prototypically  the agent (actor) and the object is prototypically the patient (theme, or undergoer). In passive sentences things are different, of course.

Comment: @AlexB.: OK so a definition partly based on the thematic roles of a prototype—seems fair. I wonder what other definitions exist. (Some modern schools of linguistics seem not to pay too much attention to thematic roles in their syntactic analysis, which I occasionally deplore.)

Comment: In one way, as for all "why" questions, the whole of the answer is "because that's the way it is". In Slavonic languages, sometimes the complement of the copula is neither nominative nor accusative, but instrumental.

Comment: @ColinFine. Could you give some examples? This sounds interesting.

Comment: @fdb. For example, Russian "Отец был рабочим (The father was a worker)" or "я хочу быть врачом" (I want to be a doctor), where the endings -им and -ом are instrumental.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In all Indo-European languages that I know, copulae are intransitive and normally take the *nominative*. So everything below will apply to other Indo-European languages, too.

It is important to distinguish between objects and other complements. A direct object, which you mean, is always a kind of complement, accompanying a transitive verb; but there are other complements that aren't direct objects and don't require a transitive verb. Note that, in Latin, only direct objects can be passivised (just as in Dutch and German, but unlike English and Greek). Cf.:

> I went **to Rome**: the complement *to Rome* is not an object, let alone a direct object, but rather a prepositional phrase.
>
> **In Italiam** ii: same as above.
>
> **Romam** ii: even though the complement is accusative, it's not a direct object. This can be seen in what happens when we make it passive:
>
> **Romam** itur a me: normally, a direct object turns into a subject when we make the sentence passive, which does not happen here.
>
> **Tibi** parceo: "I spare you": the complement is a dative, not an accusative.
>
> **Tibi** parcitur a me: this is again visible in the passive (unnatural though *a me* sounds here).
>
> **Te** video => videris a me: only direct objects become subjects when passivised.

The primary complement of a (finite) copula—or the secondary, if you count the subject as the primary complement—is always a nominative. This applies both to adjectives and substantives:

> **Canis** sum: I am a dog.
>
> **Vetus** sum: I am old.

Imagine if the adjective had to be in the accusative case: wouldn't that be weird?

> <s>**Veterem** sum.</s>

You would have an adjective sitting there alone in the accusative. It would agree with nothing. So it has to be its own constituent; but it is very strange to have an adjective that clearly describes a property of the subject ("I") but that isn't in the same case and that isn't the same constituent.

So, because the complement of a copula always describes a property or identity of the subject, it has to be in the same case as the subject. This applies as well to the accusative with infinitive:

> Dico me **canem** esse.
>
> Dico me **veterem** esse.

The complement of a copula doesn't have an independent case: it must always take the same case as that of the 'subject' of the copula even when the latter isn't in the nominative.

Answer (score 4):

In (most? all?) Indo-European languages the verb "to be" is called copulative because it joins words that represent the same thing -- in your case, "Nile" and "river." In English, Jane might answer a phone caller's question, "Is this Jane?" with the grammatically correct "Yes, this is she" -- though, since about 1600, by analogy with the general run of post-verbal pronouns, the tendency has been to answer "Yes, it's me" (see https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=2ahUKEwjyy7GAiLjdAhUnLMAKHV7eBPwQFjACegQICBAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Ffreidok.uni-freiburg.de%2Ffedora%2Fobjects%2Ffreidok%3A8431%2Fdatastreams%2FFILE1%2Fcontent&usg=AOvVaw0zzyriDMYpaOLj5Q71-nSA).

Comment: A very good point. In your example "me" indeed behaves like the direct object of the "transitive" verb "to be".

Answer (score 3):

*Sum* looks like a transitive verb in that there is a subject and an "object" (which isn't really an object). However, it is not a transitive verb. One way that it is often explained is that *sum, esse* acts like an equals sign ("="). Both sides of the equals sign have to match in case. When you say that *Nilus fluvius est*, you are saying that the Nile **is** a river, i.e. it is equivalent to a river. They are therefore interchangeable. Another example is *animal canis est*. "The animal **is** a dog." If you were to interchange *animal* and *canis*, the sentence would still be correct. "The dog **is** an animal." You could not do this for any other verb. Here is a simple example: *Puer puellam amat*. "The boy loves the girl." You can't interchange the boy and the girl because you don't know if the girl loves the boy, you only know that the boy loves the girl. This is just an easy way to understand why *sum, esse* is different in this respect.

---

In more complex sentences, you don't use the nominative. For example, one would translate "I know the boy is handsome" as *scio puerum esse pulchrum*. *esse* is once again an equals sign, matching the case of *puer*, which is accusative as it is the direct object of *scio*, to the case of *pulchrum*, which is masculine like *puer* and also in the accusative.

Comment: In your last example puerum is NOT the direct object of scio. It is the subject of esse.

Comment: @fdb I was under the impression that it was almost both because it is indirect speech; in this construction it takes the grammatical case of the direct object of _scio_ while still serving as the subject of the _esse_. Is there something I'm just missing about the grammatical terminology here (which is entirely possible)?

Comment: @fdb: It could be argued that *puerum* is in limbo: on the one hand, it cannot by itself be the entire object of the main verb, as that is probably the whole a.c.i.; on the other, it can in certain cases become the subject by itself when a sentence with an a.c.i. is passivised, which is ordinarily the sign of a direct object, i.e. *dicunt eum afuisse  => dicitur afuisse*.

Comment: The subject of an infinitive is accusative, regardless of the syntactic environment.

Comment: @fdb Could you direct me to an example where an accusative + infinitive is used not in indirect speech? I tried finding something myself but all that comes up are examples of indirect speech.

Comment: @SamK "... cum aliquis dicat se profectum esse ad exercitum" (Cic. Inv. 1.87) or "Credo edepol equidem dormire Solem" (Pl. Am. 282) - the examples are from Pinkster 2015: 736-737. Not sure how you understand "indirect speech" but accusativus cum infinitivo is only possible in a subordinate clause, obviously.

Comment: @AlexB. Perhaps I am making a mistake or something in using the term "indirect speech", but those examples look to me what I would consider indirect speech/indirect statement, which is why I think my own terminology is what is incorrect, rather than the concept.

Comment: @Sam K I see. The infinitive - in our case a part of the accusativus cum infinitivo construction- is a non-finite verb form, hence it cannot be used as the predicate of the main (stand-alone) clause. What you call “indirect speech” in this case, e.g. *scio puerum esse pulchrum*, is known as a subordinate (or dependent) clause.

Comment: @SamK. The acc. c. inf. construction is used also with impersonal verbs like oportet. This cannot be analysed as indirect speech. L/S quotes from Plautus: “servum hercle te esse oportet et nequam et malum,” "you must be a truly good-for-nothing slave".

Answer (score 2):

A less-technical answer that could help the less technical (although it could be less precise):

This happens in most (if not all?) languages with declensions.

One way to see it, put in simple words, is that a so-called *copulative* verb (like *to be*) **is not a proper action** with an object, a recipient and a number of complements/modifiers. It is instead **a way of describing**/classifying the subject.

Whatever you say as the predicate of a copulative sentence (A is B) is something about the subject, modifying the subject itself. Thus, it is reasonable for the predicate (B) to agree with the subject (A).

It becomes apparent when the predicate is an adjective: in *The dog is small*, small is qualifying the dog, (almost?) the same as saying *the small dog* as a subject of a different sentence: *the small dog bit my hand*.

Comment: Definitely not all languages - for example, in (formal) Arabic the verb "to be" (كان) takes the accusative case for the complement.